# Triggering :hover Repaint on DOM change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have UI control in a div. The entire div has a hover effect. If the user gets an error, an absolutely positioned div covers the control and asks how to proceed. The control is no longer hovered, but a repaint isn't triggered until the user moves the mouse. Is there a known way to solve this problem? I'm using Chrome

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acbabis/L655r/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="hoverable inner-div">
        <button class="clickme">Click Me</button><br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('.clickme').one('click', function() {
        $('.hoverable').append(
            '<br/><div class="touch">Move the mouse here. Hold Still</div>');
    })

    $('.container').on('mouseenter', '.touch', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
        $('.container').append(
            '<div class="cover inner-div"><br/><br/><br/>Move the mouse now</div>');
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.inner-div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 50px 100px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hoverable {
    background-color: blue;
}

.hoverable:hover {
    background-color: green;
}

.cover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, .5);
    padding: 150px 100px 50px 100px;
}
```

EDIT: I'm aware there are ways to solve this with JS, and I'm willing to use JS; but I'm curious if anyone can show me a CSS/HTML-only way to trigger a repaint. Of course, if I only get JS solutions, I'll accept the best one.

Comment: Is it necessary to append things as you have? You could append `.hoverable` instead of `.container` and still get the hover effect. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/L655r/4/)

Comment: behaves differently in Firefox, btw

Comment: @badAdviceGuy The point of my question is to *not* get the hover effect when the control is blocked. I'm sorry I was unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The css way

You could add a css rule based on a sibling selector like this:

```
.cover + .hoverable  {
    background-color: blue;
 }
```

This assumes you `prepend` `.cover` to `.container` and you probably have to set z-indices on `.cover` and `.hoverable`.

Reflected in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L655r/8/

### The js way

You could generally force a repaint on your `.hoverable` or the `.clickme` with this simple

**jQuery plugin**:

```
$(function() {
    $.fn.redraw = function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.hide();

        setTimeout(function(){
            $this.show();
        },0);

        return $this;
    };
});
```

**Usage**:

```
$('.hoverable').redraw();
```

**Fiddle**:

http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/L655r/5/